# Where clause in firestore python API isn't working for date ticks format

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with cloud firestore with an API in Python. I need to make a where clause to extract some users that meet the condition that the date that your account was processed is less than the date that was updated.

The problem with these dates is that they are in tick format:

```
'last_processed': 637053568312425740,
'last_updated': 637053568312425740,
```

It seems that they are int numbers so I should be able to make a simple comparation and only take the values that meet this condition, but it is not working, this is what I have done so far:

```
persons = 
db.collection(u'collections').where(u'last_processed', u'<', 
u'last_updated')
person_docs = persons.stream()
for person_doc in person_docs:
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(person_doc.id, person_doc.to_dict()))
```

I can extract all the content in this table without this where clause, and also if I apply different where clauses for other variables in the table it is working, so can someone explain me why is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of call can't be made using Firestore. This is more similar to a SQL statement that would run some operation before returning data.

With the type of operation you're trying to do here, you're better off doing it client side or storing an indicator with the data when you initially add it.

I would add a boolean marker that you can call (e.g. all from blanklabelcom_persons where shouldBeProcessed == true, and update that to false after it's updated, etc.